# should I use ts function before using auto.arima in r for forecasting?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I tried to use `auto.arima` function in R to know the suitable forecasting model, the first time I use `ts` function before `auto.arima`, the result was:

```
auto.arima(temp)
Series: temp 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,1)[12]
```

but when I applied it without `ts`, the result was:

```
auto.arima(Temperature)
Series: Temperature 
ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean
```

so which one is correct?
and how can I figure out its residual?

Comment: If you don't provide a ts object it will use as.ts(y) where y is the object you provide it.

Comment: Put your important codes in the post to make it reproducible.

Comment: The code I've used:
X<-ts(y, start = c(2008,1), frequency = 12)
plot(X)
P<-auto.arima(X, D=1)
finalmodel = arima(X, order = c(2, 0, 2), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12))
summary(finalmodel)
Forecastmodel = forecast(finalmodel, h=24)
Forecastmodel
autoplot(Forecastmodel)

when I tried the same without ts(...) some variables had a straight line as forecasting
is this the right way?